# ad.xaml file is not including in my project

Tags: xamarin

i had a project in that i created another xaml file named as ab.xaml. once i have created then in my solution only ad.xaml.cs is visible and ad.xaml in not visible it is visile in doted formet means this is not included. if i try to include by right click and include file it,s not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ68e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ68e.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to create new file and copy code from prev xaml and cs files.

Also you can open `.csproj` file and check how does your file are added.

There must be 2 sections

```
<Page Include="Views\ad.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</Page>
```

and

```
<Compile Include="Views\ad.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ad.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Comment: I have created new file but new file also not included

Comment: could you add .csproj file

Comment: nope. it created .csproj and .projitems but they are not openable it shows eror

Comment: did you try to open it in notepad++?